# I'm installing Hive 2.0.0 with Hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, apache-hive

I' trying to install Hive 2.0.0 with Hadoop 2.7.2

But I don't know what's the problem in my execution

```
parallels@ubuntu:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin$ ./bin/hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Fri Oct 14 05:07:53 PDT 2016 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Oct 14 05:07:53 PDT 2016:
Booting Derby (version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446)) instance a816c00e-0157-c317-6794-00000215e210 
on database directory /usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/metastore_db in READ ONLY mode with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@311d617d. 
Loaded from file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/derby-10.10.2.0.jar.
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_101-b13
user.dir=/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
os.version=3.13.0-32-generic
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

and then no reaction

what's the problem??

I execute *./bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby already* command

and I'm running hadoop (./start.dfs.sh) and no problem in hadoop

How can fix it??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when I deleted the binding between `Hadoop` and `HIVE` the issue was fixed.

- `/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar`
- `/usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
```

It seems like you are not permitted to create and write to derby.log. You could try running hive as root to check if that's the case.